# How can I automatically link local npm package?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm buidling two private npm packages that depends on each other.

Say that I have :

```
project
  /my-commons
     package.json :
     {
       name : "my-commons",
       version : "0.0.1"
       ...
     }

  /my-server
     package.json :
     {
       dependencies : {
          "my-commons" : "0.0.1"
       }
     }
```

I can use 'npm link' to install the 'commons' package. So anyone willing to 
start working on server has to do :

- checkout project
- cd my-server
- npm link ../my-commons
- npm install

And a symlink to ../my-commons is added in /my-server/node_modules, and everything's fine.

Is there however a way to tell npm that 'my-commons' package will *always* be in that folder out there, so that you could just do :

- checkout project
- cd my-server
- npm install

Or am I missing something obvious here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Maybe.

But first: If `my-commons` is needed by `my-server` then it is most likely a good idea to keep it in `my-server/node_modules` even if that is redundant. In most cases it's best keep a module's dependencies isolated from the rest of your application.

In that scenario, `npm link` can be used during development, when you're working on `my-commons` and want to use the changes in `my-server` without having to `npm publish my-commons`.

In production you will not want to use `npm link`, because dependent modules will lose control over which version of the linked module they end up with. If `my-server` depends on `my-commons` 0.1.0, but you `npm link`ed your 1.0.1-pre-release version of the `my-commons` module all hell might break loose.

*However*, since version 1.2.10 (shipping with node 0.8.19) NPM supports peer dependencies.
Peer dependencies allow you to specify that `my-server` requires that `my-commons` be installed "besides" `my-server`. This does *not* enable you to `require("my-commons")` inside `my-server` but could be useful if `my-server` is a plugin for `my-commons`.
For more information: http://blog.nodejs.org/2013/02/07/peer-dependencies/

And finally, since you said that you are developing *private* packages: If installing the packages is what is causing trouble for you, because you can't publish your packages to the public NPM registry, have a look at alternative ways to specify dependencies (git-, http-URLs, TGZ files): https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies

Comment: Thanks, my use case is the one you describe, so in practice I really want to have my-server/node-modules/my-commons ; my question was just : "is there a way to write 'my-server/package.json' so that devs don't have to run 'npm link' ". Pure lazyness, I know...