# How to automatically link npm packages at installation time?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm working on a larger project that is split into a number of **npm** packages. There are several dependencies between the packages. The whole code base is stored in a main directory like this:

```
main/
  pkg1/
  pkg2/
  ...
```

Suppose that *pkg2* depends on *pkg1*, so in `main/pkg2/package.json` I have:

```
"dependencies": {
  "pkg1": "^0.1.0"
}
```

I have linked my packages together using `npm link`. However when I start development on a new machine or for some reason I have to reinstall the packages I can't simply say `npm install` in `pkg2/`. It would fail because `pkg1` couldn't be found. (It's not published, but anyway, I want the local version because I'm developing both packages).

Of course I can do all the linking manually than call `npm install` but it's a hassle. Is there any way to do it in a single step?

*My previous research:*

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38855927/npm-link-done-at-install-time-inside-package-json) question proposes writing a *preinstall* script, but I don't want to keep linking in production, only in the development environment, as [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20529986/2599894) answer points it out.

I've also tried `npm link` in `pkg1/` then `npm install --link` in `pkg2/`. According to the manual,

> The --link argument will cause npm to link global installs into the local space in some cases.

Not in my case though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [zelda](https://github.com/feross/zelda) for this. Written by Feross, it was designed for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a fan of doing it this way; I'd generally prefer running a local repository or using git URLs for dependencies like this.

That said, if you want to keep using npm link you can always use the preinstall script approach but not use the preinstall key.

```
"autolink": "cd ../project1 && npm link && cd ../project2 && npm link project1_name",
```

Then in your cli you can do `$ npm run autolink` when you first setup a dev env.

Comment: Paul, can you link me to some resource that describes your preferred way? I don't really understand what do you mean, but it may be useful as I plan to host my packages on Github.  Anyway, thanks for the idea of the autolink script. In the meantime I figured out that my real problem is to find out the right order of visiting package directories and running the scripts. It's not obvious when I have a handful of packages.